# Jersey 2.0 SpringBoot Client Filter Auto-wiring failing - nullpointerexception

Tags: spring-boot, jersey

I have followed the docs to configure Jersey 2.0 with Springboot.

```
@Component
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyConfig() {
        super();
        register(AccountResource.class);
        register(CustomerAccountResource.class);
     //   register(new ClientLoggingFilter());
        register(new ServerLoggingFilter());
        register(HapiExceptionMapper.class);
        register(ConstraintViolationExceptionMapper.class);
        register(GeneralExceptionMapper.class);
        property(ServerProperties.BV_SEND_ERROR_IN_RESPONSE, true);
    }
}
```

I am registering two filters,

```
@Component
@PreMatching
@Priority(Integer.MIN_VALUE)
public class ServerLoggingFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter{
```

and

```
@Component
public class ClientLoggingFilter implements ClientRequestFilter, ClientResponseFilter{
```

I am using Jersey Server and Jersey Client in my application.

I have configured Jersey Client as a bean so that there is only one instance of it.

```
@Configuration
public Class XClient {

@Bean
public Client client() {
return ClientBuilder
                .newBuilder()
                .sslContext(sslContext)
                .build()
                .register(new ClientLoggingFilter());
}
}
```

When i am autowiring another spring managed Bean in my ClientLoggingFilter, I am getting a null pointer exception. The same bean works fine in the ServerLoggingFilter. I hope someone can help me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out,

```
@Configuration
public Class XClient {

@Autowired
ClientLoggingFilter loggingFilter;

@Bean
public Client client() {
return ClientBuilder
                .newBuilder()
                .sslContext(sslContext)
                .build()
                .register(loggingFilter);
}
}
```

had to autowire the filter in the configuration class.